# Change header for login page

Tags: laravel-5

I have below login page for Laravel auth. The header it shows is the header which is at layouts/header.php. I want to define another header for it. How can I do so?

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('page', __('Login'))

@section('auth_content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [section directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#template-inheritance) around your header and overwrite that section in your view.

**layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<header>
  @section('header')
    {{-- existing header --}}
    @include('layouts.header')
  @show
</header>
```

**Login view**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('page', __('Login'))

@section('header')
  {{-- new header --}}
  @include('layout.other_header')
@endsection
```

This will still use the old header for existing pages but you can overwrite it in any view.